# Using a template function as a template param in another function

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++14, std-function

I was wondering, how I can do the following in C++?

```
template <typename T>
T doSomething(T x, T y) {
  T result = /*do something*/;

  return result;
}

template <typename T , typename V> 
T doMore(**input doSomething as template**, V v){
  T result = doSomething<V>(v,0); 
  return result;
}
```

I am basically trying to use a template function with its template valuetype in another function as such, is there any way to do that?

Comment: So you want to use `doMore` like `doMore(doSomething, some_v_value)` (please [edit] your question to clarify)? Then I recommend you take a hint from the standard library, where all functions are passed using a single templated argument type. I also recommend you use lambdas rather than `doSomething` directly in the call.

Comment: Your description is really confusing, especially because you are already using `doSomething` inside `doMore`. Is the question about how to pass any kind of function to `doMore` so it can call that internally? (Then you might want to rename what you are calling inside that function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass (the set of) function template as argument (you can pass specific instantiation though).

You might pass functor to solve your issue:

```
template <typename T>
T doSomething(T x, T y) {
  T result = /*do something*/;

  return result;
}

template <typename F, typename V> 
T doMore(F f, V v){
  T result = f(v, V{0}); 
  return result;
}
```

And then

```
doMore([](auto x, auto y){ return doSomething(x, y); }, 42);
```

Comment: I have another question: when I have a function call like this: doSomething<int,float>(...), how would the function be defined as to be able to make that call with double values ?

Comment: Your `doSomething` takes only one template parameter, so `doSomething<int,float>(...)` is wrong. And anyway there is no way to remap a function instantiation to another one with different template (but it might be possible with template classes).